# Git push failed in Rstudio

Tags: github, rstudio

it kept showing me that "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart" when I tried to push after committing.

Comment: You can pull latest changes first and then try commit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your history: you should see commits on origin that you don't have

[image: http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/images/rstudio.png]

You would normally solve this with a `git pull`, if your branch is associated with origin/yourBranch (type `git branch -avv` to check)

See [this thread](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Pages/git-errors-when-trying-to-upload-to-github-pages/td-p/32657) as an illustration.